# negation of a relation

Tags: elementary-set-theory, formal-languages

When I try to write the formal negation of that a relation is reflexive, with a positive sentence(no $\neg$ symbol), I don't really know what  the "positive" negation of $x$ is in relation with $x$ is.

So the definition of reflexivity is this: $\forall x\in X:xRx$

1.) $\neg(\forall x\in X:xRx)$

2.) $\exists x\in X: \neg xRx$

And here I'm stuck.

Comment: I do not see any error... Maybe the question asks you to do exactly what you have done: do not limit yourself to put $\lnot$ in front, but move it inside...

Comment: It is hard to find a way to say "not $xRy$" without the negation sign. Only for some special binary predicates, like $=$ and $\in$ we have a built-in negated form: $\ne$ and $\notin$.

Comment: Since $R\subset X\times X$ one could write $\exists x\in X\colon (x,x)\notin R$.

Comment: @Mauro ALLEGRANZA I see. Is a positive sentence possible with words maybe? Like: Some elements of $X$ are related to themselves.

Comment: What is the text of the problem ? and what is the context ?

Comment: There is an element in $X$ that is un-related to itself.

Comment: @Mauro ALLEGRANZA Formulate a positive sentence that says: A relation is not reflexive.

Comment: I agree with Mauro ... I think your 2) is considered a positive sentence as its main operator is not a negation.